# Generate dynamic list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose I have an alphabet:

```
A = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
```

I would like to generate every possible combination of length n (n-mer). For example for `n=2: AA, AT, ..., GG`. To keep things interesting I was experimenting with generating these with list comprehensions in a dynamic way. Is this possible in python? The only obvious path is to use `eval()` and generate a the required string dynamically. However, I was curious to see if there was a less clunky approach.

Answer (score 6):

*every possible* of length 2, would be - (but you're probably after `permutations`, `combinations` or `combinations_with_replacement` from `itertools`...)

```
from itertools import product

A = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
print list(product(A, repeat=2))

[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'A'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'T'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'G'), ('G', 'A'), ('G', 'T'), ('G', 'C'), ('G', 'G')]
```

This is equivalent to `[(a,b) for a in A for b in A]` but scales more easily should you want 3, 4, a thousand etc...

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> A = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
>>> print list(combinations(A,2))
[('A', 'T'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'G')]
```

Or possibly (to get the repeats):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> print list(combinations_with_replacement(A,2))
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'T'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'G'), ('G', 'G')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want both `'AT'` and `'TA'`, then [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) is probably what you are looking for:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> A = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
>>> [''.join(x) for x in combinations_with_replacement(A, 2)]
['AA', 'AT', 'AC', 'AG', 'TT', 'TC', 'TG', 'CC', 'CG', 'GG']
```